# Make textbox add new line automatically when it's end of a line

Tags: c#, winforms

This seems an easy task, however, I can't find any working method to do it. I want a `textbox` add extra line to itself automatically when we type at the end of a full line (so, we are redirected to a new line).
Maybe I show it better as follows:  
Textbox current value: `asdfghj`(this is full length of a textbox)
We type new string after `j`: `asd`. And I see:

```
asd
```

Only one line, to see the first line I need to scroll up `^`  
And I want to see:

```
asdfghj
asd
```

Two lines.

I tried this code:

```
  private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Size size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(textBox1.Text, textBox1.Font);
        textBox1.Width = size.Width;
        textBox1.Height = size.Height;
    }
```

But the extra line is being created when I press `enter` or `shift-enter` only. And I want it to be automatically added. I also have `Multiline=true` and `Wordwrap=true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kind of a hack, but try this and see if it fits your needs:

```
    int previouslines = 1;
    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int size=textBox2.Font.Height;
        int lineas = textBox2.Lines.Length;
        int newlines = 0;
        if (textBox2.Text.Contains(Environment.NewLine))
        {
            newlines = textBox2.Text.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None).Length - 1;
            lineas += newlines - (textBox2.Lines.Length - 1);
        }

        for(int line_num= 0;line_num<textBox2.Lines.Length;line_num++)
        {
            if (textBox2.Lines[line_num].Length > 1)
            {
                int pos1=textBox2.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(line_num);
                int pos2= pos1 + textBox2.Lines[line_num].Length-1;
                int y1 = textBox2.GetPositionFromCharIndex(pos1).Y;
                int y2 = textBox2.GetPositionFromCharIndex(pos2).Y;
                if (y1 != y2)
                {
                    int aux = y2+size;
                    lineas = (aux / size);
                    if (y1 != 1)
                    {
                        lineas++;
                    }

                    lineas += newlines - (textBox2.Lines.Length - 1);
                }
            }
        }

        if (lineas > previouslines)
        {
            previouslines++;
            textBox2.Height = textBox2.Height + size;
        }
        else if (lineas<previouslines)
        {
            previouslines--;
            textBox2.Height = textBox2.Height - size;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This works! Only one little thing, when we type some text we are adding lines as i wish, but when we clear the textbox the size doesn't change to one line.

Comment: Try edited answer for adjusting textbox on clearing text

Comment: A few bugs: if type continiously 2nd symbol in 2nd line causes to create 1 extra line, and it's always show in the bottom. If you clear the text (many lines) only 1 line is deleted, after you type a symbol - another line is deleted, 1 more symbol - last line deleted. Also if you type a symbol, delete it and type again, it  causes to create a line, so you have 1 symbol typed and 2 lines. And it's always shown as empty line at the bottom no matter how long text is

Comment: Have you copied the entire method? i don't detect the bugs you're saying. There are some changes besides the new else if

Comment: Interesting, in a new project bug with 2nd symbol in 2nd line is gone. But other bugs are the [same](https://sendvid.com/cdgrffzc)

Answer (score 0):

If `MultiLine` is set, you could do it like this:

1) Estimate the lenght of the last line of text in the `TextBox` by splitting it into an array (may be not the fasted possible)

2) If that line has more the `MAX_CHARS` chars, then

3) Take all of the text, except the last char, and add new line and then that char

4) Correct selection and position

```
    const int MAX_CHARS = 10;
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] sTextArray = textBox1.Text.Split( new string[] {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries );
        int nLines = sTextArray.Length;
        string sLastLine = sTextArray[nLines -1];
        if (sLastLine.Length > MAX_CHARS)
        {
            int nTextLen = textBox1.Text.Length;
            string sText = textBox1.Text.Substring(0, nTextLen - 1) + Environment.NewLine + textBox1.Text[nTextLen - 1];
            textBox1.Text = sText;
            textBox1.SelectedText = "";
            textBox1.Select(nTextLen +2, 0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This kind of works combined with my code. But it adds lines properly after 2nd line. Also we are able to go back and add more chars to any previous string, Also characters' sizes are different and 10x`w` fills the line, but 10x`f` does not. Looks not good overall.

Comment: Take this as a starting point. Instead of MAX_CHARS you can use youre MeasureText  or any other. And in case the user goes back, you could do the check on that current line. The main point is to analyse that line and insert NewLine by using substring.